# String comparison in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Here i am trying to print unique values in both strings ,

```
string1 = "wana"
string2 ="sana"
string3 = ""

for wrd in string1 :
    if wrd not in string2:
        string3+=wrd
```

The above code can compare string1 and return output which is not in string2,  i want unique value from both string,here **S and W** needs to be appenedd to string3 .
How to do it without using functions and classes ?

Regards

Comment: what's wrong with above approach? is it giving any error or wrong output?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar ,  the above will only print w but not S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one approach. Using `set`

**Ex:**

```
string1 = "wana"
string2 ="sana"

string3 =  "".join(set(string1) ^ set(string2))
print(string3)
```

**Output:**

```
sw
```

Comment: thanks rakesh, this is the second question you are answering mine and both of them are well done

Comment: symmetric difference.....https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/symmetric_difference

Comment: so , its comapring each position. is it possible to modify this for any string like , `string1 =fort`, `string 2 =flour`  and the result is `tlu`

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate again, this time over the other string:

```
string1 = "wana"
string2 ="sana"
string3 = ""

for wrd in string1 :
    if wrd not in string2:
        string3+=wrd

for wrd in string2 :
    if wrd not in string1:
        string3+=wrd

print(string3)
```

Comment: oh.. yeah, how i missed it , its a simple another for loop. .

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = "sana"
str2 = "wana"
str3=""
for i in range(len(str1)):
    if(str1[i] != str2[i]):
        str3+=str1[i]+str2[i]
print(str3)
```

Comment: Maybe this help you to get desired output in single loop

Comment: How to do it if the positions are interchanged for strings ?

Comment: U mean to say as asna and awna?